# How to replace/update log4j for Artifactory?

Tags: log4j, artifactory

Is there any instruction for replacing/upgrading the log4j module for JFrog?

Answer (score 6):

Here is the formal answer from JFrog.
Disclaimer, I'm working at JFrog

> On 10 December 2021, a RCE (remote code execution) exploit was exposed on several versions of the Apache Log4j 2 utility.
>
> Affected code exists in log4j core libraries: log4j-core-*.jar, versions 2.0 to 2.14.1.
>
> Following internal research and validation by the JFrog Security and R&D teams, we can confirm that JFrog services are not affected by this vulnerability (CVE-2021-44228). First, we have validated that JFrog services are not configured to implement the log4j-core package. Additionally, we can confirm that the JDK version used in JFrog services (e.g. Artifactory) contain default protection against remote class loading via JNDI objects. Therefore, no action is required by JFrog customers regarding this issue for JFrog solutions.
>
> JFrog Security and Xray product teams have updated the Xray database with CVE information regarding this vulnerability, and this information will be available for Xray customers to assist in detection and remediation across customer portfolios.
>
> JFrog has examined and validated that none of the following products reference the vulnerable libraries:
>
> Artifactory 6.x and 7.x, and the accompanying Access service
>
> - Xray
> - Distribution
> - Mission Control
> - Insights

Source: [GENERAL: JFrog Services Are Not Affected by Vulnerability CVE-2021-44228](https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/general-jfrog-services-are-not-affected-by-vulnerability-cve-2021-44228/)

Comment: "we can confirm that the JDK version used in Artifactory contains default protection against remote class loading via JNDI objects"; there has been some misleading information about this. The latest Java versions can most likely still be vulnerable to RCE (see [comment](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/pull/608#issuecomment-991396409)); additionally there are other attack surfaces such as [credentials extraction](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/pull/608#issuecomment-991354707). Though if you don't use log4j-core, then that does not matter for you.

Comment: Do you have a link to the official site with this statement?

Comment: @TheNail JFrog made a statement in the "Are JFrog products vulnerable?" section of this recent blog post: https://jfrog.com/blog/log4shell-0-day-vulnerability-all-you-need-to-know/